# git-stage the current file-visiting buffer?

Tags: git, version-control

I've never really used `vc` but it looks like it only supports add or commit actions.

I reckon `magit` must have some of the machinery to achieve this, but browsing its codebase didn't reveal anything obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you don't want to:

- first: call magit-status
- second: press s to stage the file you want

So, let me suggest this function, courtesy of [Nicholas Bishop](https://github.com/nicholasbishop/emacs-conf/blob/master/git.el):

```
(defun git-add-current-buffer ()
  "call 'git add [current-buffer]'"      
  (interactive)
  (let* ((buffile (buffer-file-name))
         (output (shell-command-to-string
                  (concat "git add " (buffer-file-name)))))
    (message (if (not (string= output ""))
                 output
               (concat "Added " buffile)))))
```

The next thing is probably set a custom shortcut for that function.